# Coverity vs nested functions: PARSE_ERROR error code

Tags: c, nested-function, coverity

It looks like Coverity doesn't handle nested functions in C code, I get a lot of PARSE_ERRORs. The code is not mine and is unlikely to be changed in a hurry although it'll be extended and scanned with Coverity. Any known workarounds to get it scanned anyway?

Comment: AFAIK nested functions are an extension of gcc and are not part of the standard.

Comment: simple fix, Do not nest functions, that 'feature' is not part of the C language.

Answer (score 1):

`cov-emit` doesn't currently support GNU nested functions. However, these cases should be handled by the error recovery mechanism--the defects should be prefixed with `RW` which indicates a recoverable error.

`cov-emit`'s error recovery works on a per-function basis, so when it sees an error like this, it won't emit the affected function (in this case, neither the nested nor enclosing function). This might cause some false negatives (and potentially false positives) but so long as you are still capturing most of the code (>95% TUs or so, assuming that most functions in the codebase don't use nested functions), these should be safe to ignore.